# Querying over the content of an @ElementCollection. Hibernate Criteria way

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity which contains `@ElementCollection`field with enums.

```
public enum StatusType { 
    NEW, PENDING, CLOSED;
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "status_type", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id")}) 
    @Column(name = "status_type", nullable = false)
    private Set<StatusType > statusTypes = new HashSet<StatusType >();

    ...
}
```

Now I want to get all entities which contains status `NEW` or `PENDING` (or both).

I.e.

```
Criteria criteria = session().createCriteria( MyEntity.class );
List<StatusType > statuses = new ArrayList()<>;
statuses.add(StatusType.NEW);
statuses.add(StatusType.PENDING);

criteria.createAlias( "statusTypes", "statusTypes" );
criteria.add( Restrictions.in( "statusTypes", statuses) );
```

This code doesn't work :

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: collection was not an
>   association: com.blabla.MyEntity.statusTypes

So, How I can get all `MyEnitity` which are have inside `statusTypes` field  `NEW` or `PENDING` values (or both)

Also, please not, that I don't want to use HQL because I need to support optional parameters. So I need dynamically add restrictions if parameters are not null or not empty.

Comment: What happens if you use `criteria.createAlias("statusTypes", "statusType"); criteria.add(Restrictions.in("statusType", statuses));`? Why don't you use JPQL for such a static query?

Comment: @JBNizet please look at updated answer

Comment: Please try with a different alias, as in my comment.

Comment: @JBNizet tried with your query, same exception: `org.hibernate.MappingException: collection was not an association`. Removing alias at all gives another exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a pretty old question, but there is a very basic mistake here and no one has spotted it.

You need to change the last two lines to:

```
criteria.createAlias( "statusTypes", "statusTypes" );
criteria.add( Restrictions.in( "statusTypes.elements", statuses) );
```

Think of `statustypes` as its own database-table (it actually is). To query it, you need to join it (`createAlias`), and then query on *a property of the joined table*. In your example you are trying to query on the joined table itself.

As this is not a table with its own entity-mapping, but an `ElementCollection`, the column you need to query is the special phrase '`elements`'.

Comment: You definitely saved my day (or more precise: night)!